# Stock ROM won't flash

Tags: rom-flashing, unbricking

Question HOW DO I FLASH THE STOCK ROM ON HOMTOM HT7 WHEN SP FLASH TOOL SAYS BROM ERROR : S_FT_ENABLE_DRAM_FAIL (0xFC0)

Info 
OK I ultra hard bricked my Doogee HOMTOM HT7 (base model) 5.1 lollipop  1gb ram 8gb rom mtk6580a 
I say ultra hard bricked because when I tried  OEM unlock in adb it bricked it to the point that 4 different  PCs wouldn't detect it at a with installed drivers I resently read a way to fix it to where a PC wood detect it so I did what the guide said witch was disassemble phone down to the  circuit board and sold a wire from one point to another and it did work so now PC detects it so does SP flash tool scatter file from ROM is accepted but when I try to flash ROM I get  error message stating BROM ERROR : S_FT_ENABLE_DRAM_FAIL (0xFC0) so what do I do

If you want more info ask I tried to give all that i thought was needed 
Sorry for bad spelling and punctuation

Answer (score 0):

First time, The problem of your phone was a wrong **preloader** used on your **MT6580A**.

- While you are using test points to force preloader port then you have to try different preloaders from different similar Firmwares based on MT6580A.

**P.S:** **THIS OPERATION IS RISKY** but it should resolve your problem.

Comment: Ok so do I decompile a ROM and switch the pre loader and recompile it or what do I have to do just flash different firmware from different ROM sharing the same preloader until something happens or my PC won't  it won't recognize it again?

Comment: Try to find older ROMS for your model and use their preloaders one by one, replace the preloader before flashinf each time and make sure you're using Firmware Upgrade.